# Content Elements - Is there a Video add-on compatable with Vimeo?

Tags: content-elements, video

I'm trying to give a client the ability to add Vimeo videos in their entries in conjunction with Content Elements. There seems to be only one video fieldtype compatable with CE -  Embed video by krea but that only allows youtube uploads. Anyone else got this working or knows a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no compatible add-on. Developer tells me there is something in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative would be to create a text fieldtype in which the client could simply enter the video ID, which you would then parse into the Vimeo embed code within the template.  It's not perfect, but it's a potential solution.  You might simply have to do an element name lookup to distinguish it from any other textfield options you have provided as an element.

Comment: Thanks Jean. I've been down that route but it won't work for this client. I'll have to move the video code out of content elements for the moment.

Comment: It would be AWESOME if Channel Videos became a Content Elements compatible fieldtype.

Comment: Ive opted for this. It works great and users understand how to copy and paste the embed code (iframe). Very easy to implement.